# Using for loop with read command

Tags: linux, shell-script, read

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter a number >"
read number
for var in $number
do
  read number
  echo $var
done
echo "Go!"
```

I want numbers from 8-1 to print vertically and say go at the end. When I run the code only 8 and Go! prints out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `seq`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter a number > "
read number
seq "$number" -1 1
echo "Go!"
```

Output:

```
Enter a number > 8
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
Go!
```

---

To improve your code a bit, you could output the prompt to `stderr`:

```
>&2 echo -n "Enter a number > "
```

or use the `-p` option from `read`:

```
read -p 'enter a number > ' number
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your code is not working as expected is due to

1. reading the number in each iteration in the loop, and
2. never decrementing/incremeting the number in a `while` loop, or alternatively
3. never creating the correct range for the `for` loop to iterate over.

In `zsh`, you could do it with

```bsh
read '?Enter a number > '
printf '%s\n' {1..$REPLY} 'Go!'
```

This reads from the user into `REPLY` and then uses that data in a brace expansion that creates the list of numbers (if the user entered a valid number).  At the end of the list we tack on the string `Go!` and then print all those strings with newlines as delimiters using `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter a number: "
read number
for ((i=number; i>0; i--))
do
  echo $i
done
echo "Go!"
```

Or:

```
echo -n "Enter a number: "
read number
while ((number>0))
do
  echo $number
  let number--
done
echo "Go!"
```